# Regarding One hot encoding in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am making a project for my college in machine learning.
the tile of the project is Crop yield prediction using machine learning and I want to perform multiple linear Regression on my dataset .
the data set include parameters like state-district- monthly rainfall , temperature ,soil factor ,area and per hectare yield.

## create an instance of OneHotEncoder

`ohe = OneHotEncoder()`

## fit the encoder to the categorical columns in the DataFrame and transform them

`feature_array = ohe.fit_transform(df[['State', 'Dist', 'Month', 'Season', 'Crop']]).toarray()`

## get the categories used by the encoder

`feature_labels = ohe.get_feature_names(['State', 'Dist', 'Month', 'Season', 'Crop'])`

## create a new DataFrame with the one-hot encoded columns

``df_encoded = pd.DataFrame(feature_array, columns=feature_labels`)`

## concatenate the original and encoded DataFrames

`df_new = pd.concat([df, df_encoded], axis=1)`

## create the feature matrix X and target vector y

`X = pd.concat([df_new.drop(['Yield'], axis=1), df_encoded], axis=1)`
`y = df_new['Yield']`

## create an instance of the LinearRegression class

`model = LinearRegression()`

## fit the model to the data

`model.fit(X, y)`

Comment: I am getting this error :-ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').